# LinkedIn iOS SDK is not working properly in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I am implementing LinkedIn integration in my current iOS app and found that it suddenly stops working and found that SDK makes some changes. Please check this link:
https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

What is the solution to this?

Comment: http://www.whitneyland.com/2011/03/iphone-oauth.html

Hope this help you.

Comment: this hasn't been updated in several years, does it still work? is it still the best way?

Comment: tried so much but still not working...